# Сортировка чисел в set по элементам, на которые они указывают в массиве

Tags: c++, сортировка, set

Мне нужно, чтобы `set` сортировал числа по элементам, на которые они указывают в массиве. Как это сделать?

```cpp
template<>
class set<int> {

    int* arr;

public:
    set(int* arr) : arr(arr) {

    }

    // какой-то метод надо переопределить?
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего не надо переопределять, надо только дать [нужный компаратор](https://ideone.com/V4HQGj):

```
int a[10] = { 8,2,4,9,1,3,7,5,6,0 };

set<int*,function<bool(int*,int*)>> s([](int*a,int*b){ return *a < *b; });

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    s.insert(&a[i]);

for(auto p: s) cout << *p << endl;
```

Comment: Так здесь вставляется `&a[i]`, а мне нужно, чтобы вставлялось `i`, но сортировалось как `a[i1] < a[i2]`.

Comment: Ну что за беспомощность?! перепишите компаратор!

Comment: `set<int,function<bool(int,int)>> s([&a](int i,int j){ return a[i] < a[j]; });`

Comment: Я переписывал, пишет "на локальную переменную со вложенной функцией нельзя ссылаться внутри тела лямбды, если она не находится в списке записей".

Comment: Теперь спасибо.

Comment: А если я всё-таки захочу что-то переопределить, это можно сделать?

Comment: Можно, только это совсем не так просто, как вам кажется. А главное, не имеет никакого смысла - *что именно* **вы** хотите переопределять? (Я недаром выделил - вы - потому что не спрашивайте меня, что мне переопределить, а говорите сами, что именно вы намерены переопределить для достижения вашей цели.)

Comment: Чтобы был не `set<int,function<bool(int,int)>>`, а `set<int>`, но сортировка осталась той же самой. Там же, видимо, всё-таки для сортировки вызывается какой-то метод? Вот его и хочу переопределить.

Comment: А я что сделал? Переопределил метод сортировки, грубо говоря. Вам же придется переписывать далеко не один метод, так как все, что вы хотите - это вшить компаратор жестко в код. А он используется в самых разных местах...